# Angular Karma-Jasmine Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

example.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { environment as ENV } from '../../environments/environment';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

video(id): Observable<any> {
let sessionId = this.sharedService.sessionId();

return this.http.get(ENV.api_url + '&videoId=' + id)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

example.service.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from 

'@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';


describe('VideosComponent', () => {
  let component: VideosComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VideosComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ VideosComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [MockBackend]
        },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VideosComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I got **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined** when i'm trying to run tests.
I'm very new to unit testing, but I posted the code here for the unit testing files and service that returns 'get'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your service is no service.
I really recommend reading https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#heroes-and-http .

There you can see that you need to make a `constructor(private http: Http) { }`, your http is now **undefined**.

Comment: I know but I didn't paste the full service here

Comment: Then plz do so.

Comment: I think the problem is with the testing file not the service at all!

Comment: Ok if your service is running fine then use a inject and a spyOn.
inject([VideoService], (videoService: VideoService) => {
spyOn(videoService, 'method').and.returnValue(yourVideo);

Comment: Sorry but i'm new to angular, can you update or give me the full snippet anywhere? 
Thank you :)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1v0cd9y8BZ0KTQUDlhik?p=preview

Something like this.